# Is it a good idea to apply for a job with the knowledge that you will leave soon?

Tags: applications

I hope you can help me with my problem and also hope that this question is not off-topic here.

I am currently near graduation from a Austrian school for media design and business (similar to high school in the US). After graduating I am a fully trained graphic designer, which is quite common here in Austria.

I tried finding a job for the summer months in Dublin, as I will stay there for 3 months. Now, it is quite difficult finding a job in the graphic design industry, especially for 3 months only.

So is it a good idea to don't tell the potential employer that I am intending to leave after three months. Are my chances for getting a job higher.

Comment: And what after 3 months? Usually, moving out of the first job in 3 months is not a good sign.

Comment: Are you able to look specifically for internships, temporary positions, consulting, or contracting? There are entire labor markets designed specifically for short duration employment. I don't think it makes sense to apply for a permanent, full time professional job if you know you're leaving in three months, for either you or the employer's sake.

Comment: @dwizum At least not in the media and graphic design industry where I would like to work. Of course I could find a job as a waitress or something, but first I would like to try finding a job that fits to my education.

Comment: Did you consider searching for a remote position? Given that, you'll the taking up an entry level role, chances are less, but still worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

For what reasons do you need to have this 3 months job? If it is just to earn money, there are plenty of summer jobs outside of the graphic design industry.

A 3 months experience is a very short experience, so this may not be very valuable on a resume, if this is your goal. You could find small contracts though on the side, if you are willing to work freelance? That way you could expand your search outside of Dublin.

To come back to the original question, yes you have a higher chance to get a job if you do not say that you are going to leave in 3 months, there is close to nobody who will hire someone for a full time job knowing that he will leave in 3 months.

Comment: I would like to work in the graphic design industry, as it is a good preparation for my university degree I am going to do afterwards. Of course, when it comes to earning money I could find other jobs, that would be plan B. Is it even possible to quit after three months with a normal contract. I have not much working experience, especially not in Ireland.

Comment: In that case, my second paragraph is the most adapted for you I think. Working either freelance or remote for small contract(s) that would last you three months sounds the most convenient.